# How to prevent form fields from repopulating after clicking the back button?

Tags: caching, browser, coldfusion

I have a simple form which has four fields named firstName, lastName, address and phone number.

After a user fills this form and clicks the submit button, if everything goes fine, I am redirecting that user to a success page.

But on clicking the browser back button from the success page the form field values are repopulating on the form. How can I prevent this from happening?

I have already tried this code:

```
<cfheader name="cache-control"  value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfheader name="expires" value="#getHttpTimeString(now()-1)#">
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 6):

Repopulating form fields is a *good* thing, stop trying to break it.

If what you actually want is to prevent duplicate submissions, send a unique id (e.g. UUID) along with the form and keep track of the ones you've received recently (how many to keep track of depends on your application).

If you receive a duplicate you can either ignore it (and display appropriate message), or go a step further: check whether the received data has already been submitted or whether it's an attempt to change the previous submission (i.e. fixing a typo), or to create a new record (maybe firstname and phone were changed), or prompt the user to choose, or whatever.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. The biggest question to ask is "What is my ultimate goal in this?" If you simply want to keep people from resubmitting the form, Peter's suggestion is a good way to go. If you want to keep people from going back to the form, then you might want to ask yourself why. Using the back button to update the form may be undesirable, but it isn't unreasonable from a user's point of view. If you don't want double submissions, you should be checking for this on form submit.

From personal experience, reprogramming normal browser behavior can really suck.

Comment: There are a lot of cases when you don't want your fields to be repopulated.

Answer (score 6):

Repopulating the FORM fields is a good think i know but we can disable it by using
**autocomplete="off"**

Comment: autocomplete=off is very annoying when you are the user.

Comment: The `autocomplete` attribute is for pre-filling forms when you first visit the page (based on how you have filled out similar forms before), not when the back button is clicked.

Comment: Yes I know that , But it is working for my case also in all browsers.

Comment: there is a `autocomplete="on"` extension for chrome and firefox to easily overwrite this 'fix'

Comment: Which your users should not have to use.  The 'fix" is a bad one because it breaks something else.

Comment: I only use autocomplete="off" for login forms and credit card info.  Some PCI compliance evaluations require it.

Comment: autocomplete is a totally different thing than what the user asked

Answer (score 0):

This works when I run it.  First, file testform.cfm

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<CFHEADER NAME="Cache-Control" VALUE="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<!--- this is meant for legacy HTTP 1.0 servers 
- only prevents caching when used with secure communications (https://)  --->
<CFHEADER NAME="Pragma" VALUE="no-cache">
<!--- this doesn't prevent caching, 
just means for future requests that browser must contact server for fresh copy. 
cached copy used for BACK and FORWARD buttons--->
<CFHEADER NAME="Expires" VALUE="-1">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="formtarget.cfm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="x" value="" />
<input name="submitbutton" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is formtarget.cfm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<cfdump var="#form#">
</body>
</html>
```

We have those three cfheader tags in a custom tag.