# How to stop browser forward button to redirect to a page?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, coldfusion

I have a simple "Service Request Form" which are used by the users to request for different services . There is no session or login concept.

Now

1. On clicking the Submit button on "Service Request Form" it redirects the user to a "Thank-you.cfm" page.
2. If the user presses the browser back button, the form again comes with all the fields empty.
3. Now when the user clicks the browser forward button, it again shows the Thank-you.cfm page.

I do not want to show user the "Thank-you.cfm" page again on clicking browser forward button.I am also clearing the cache on this page.

For clearing the cache I am using this code

```
<cfheader name="cache-control"  value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfheader name="expires" value="#getHttpTimeString(now()-1)#">
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does the form post directly to the thank you page?

Comment: NO , the request form post to the same page and on success I am redirecting to the thank-you page.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going to get yourself into trouble if you continue down this path. Yesterday you asked [how to change the default behavior of the browser back-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970601/how-to-prevent-form-fields-from-repopulating-after-clicking-the-back-button) and today you are asking how to change the default behavior of the browser forward-button. All of the browsers have these features and (I believe) they were designed to benefit the users. While I agree that these features have given dynamic websites (and we developers) headaches over the years I do not agree that you should attempt to change their behavior. Instead you need to deal with the behavior gracefully.

It is not really clear what you are after in either of your posts. My assumption would be that you want to avoid duplicate posts of your form data (as Peter mentioned in your other question). If that is the case then you should check if the information being submitted has already been submitted and post an appropriate message to the user if so (again as Peter already mentioned in your other question).

Attempting to change how these features work is going to bite you in my opinion. It would be similar to changing the way a steering wheel works in all of the cars out there. The default behavior when you turn the steering wheel to the left is that the car turns left, well I would like to make it turn right instead...

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if the next question is "how to disable refresh button"... :/

Answer (score 0):

If you can support IE10+ you can use [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

For example `window.history.replaceState()` method.

Comment: Can you please suggest how shall i use this?

Comment: You can POST your form using AJAX and replace body with `Thank-you.cfm` on success. Then replace history state to `Thank-you.cfm` and you will have only one hstory record but `Thank-you.cfm` in url.

Comment: I am not allowed to use ajax , I am submitting the form to the same page and on success i am redirecting to the thank-you.cfm page.

Comment: If this is for a public website the solution has to work on all browsers, not just modern ones.

Comment: @DanBracuk `replaceState` was introduced only in IE10 so this supported only by modern browsers as I wrote on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Make it so the page is only displayed if post data is passed else it redirects.

I havn't used coldfusion before so I can't help you too much with the code, but I'm guessing that would be the best concept.

This way no-one is able to go onto the Thank-you.cfm page unless there is valid post data

Comment: But as the page is present in cache, the thank-you page comes on clicking the browser forward button

Comment: You also say that you are clearing the cache.  Maybe you just think you are.  Why not edit your question and add the code you are using to clear it?

Comment: @DanBracuk: added the code on the question, Please check and let me know How can i prevent the browser forward button to take the page from the cache.