# jquery counter reset issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code and even after a page refresh, the counter is not getting a reset. Please help me out in resetting the "counter". Also excuse me if there are any typo(s) or dirty coding.

Script :

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('p').click(function () {
             $(this).animate({
                 'color': 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'
             }, 500);
         });

         $('#counter').data('count', 0);
         $("#fl1").click(function () {
             $('#counter').val(function (i, val) {
                 return val == '0' ? 1 : val + 1;
             });
         });

         $('#counter').data('count', 0);
         $("#fl2").click(function () {
             $('#counter').val(function (i, val) {
                 return val == '0' ? 2 : val + 2;
             });
         });
     });
});
```

Solved Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('p').click(function() {
            $(this).animate({
              'color': 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'
              }, 500);
            });

          $('#counter').val('0');

          $("#fl1").click(function() {
            $('#counter').val(function(i, val) {
              return val == '0' ? 1 : val + 1;
              });
            });

          $("#fl2").click(function() {
          $('#counter').val(function(i, val) {
            return val == '0' ? 2 : val + 2;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

HTML :

```
<div id="fl1" style="float:left; margin: 20px 0 0 0; font-weight: bold; display: inline; cursor: pointer;">
   <p>(1)</p>
</div>
<div id="fl2" style="float:left; margin: 20px 0 0 40px; font-weight: bold; display: inline; cursor: pointer;">
   <p>(2)</p>
</div>
<br />
<form method=POST name="test" action="test.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
```

Comment: What is `.data('count', 0)` supposed to do (twice)? You're not using it anywhere.

Comment: And why are you using `val == '0' ? 1 : val + 1;`? Shouldn't it simply be `parseInt(val, 10) + 1`, do you really want string concatenation?

Comment: I intended to make "counter" 0. Count is a typo. Apologies. Yes, I want string concatenation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent form fields from repopulating after clicking the back button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970601/how-to-prevent-form-fields-from-repopulating-after-clicking-the-back-button) - I guess it's the same for page reload.

Comment: If you want to init the counter with `0`, then use `.val('0')`. And for string concatenation you should use `'0'` instead of `0` to make it unambiguous.

Comment: thanks Bergie. got it done with `$('#counter').val('0');` before the click function.