# laravel form empty when pressing browser back button in Chrome

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, laravel-5.6

In laravel, when using Chrome, is there a way to have to form populate the fields as they were before submitting when pressing the browser back button. Currently after submitting the form if I press the browser back button the form is empty.

**Edit**: I am already using value = `{{ old('input field name', 'default value') }}` after validation and it is working fine. I want the data that was entered in the form before submission to be there when the user clicks the browser back.

**Edit 2:** Looks like the issue is happening in Chrome. I tested it in Firefox and the data is retained there. So looks like it has something to do with Chrome and laravel, since a simple html form page works fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause and the solution? It seems silly that I'd need to code a way to capture the input (e.g. to the session, etc).

Comment: I haven't found a good solution yet, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972303/470749 seems related.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your form data after validation using `value = {{ old('input field name', 'default value') }}`.

**About Back button**, it depends on your browser. You can put your form data in session & can replace default value with that value. Then it will always show that data although you press back button.

Comment: Yes, I am already using `value = {{ old('input field name', 'default value') }}.` after validation and it is working fine. I want the data that was entered in the form before submission to be there when the user click the browser back like how normally any site has it.

Comment: then you need to store that value somewhere like session & then show that value instead of default value, you can use ternary operator for checking that session & default value

Comment: OK, I will try that. However, do you know why it happens, since in a regular HTML page when you click back the data is still there, so looks like laravel is (or I am) doing something that clears out the data when user click back.

Comment: I was using Chrome and it is not showing the data, but I just tried Firefox and it has the data. So it looks like the issue might be with Chrome

Comment: yes, the issue is related with browser, not with laravel

Comment: Yes. I updated my question to add all this info. Thanks for your help. Still need to figure out why it is happening

Comment: What is your local server stack? WAMP, XAMPP? This was a WAMP issue I faced that fixed by installing XAMPP.

Comment: I am using xamp.