# How to handle in django user going back after payment confirmation?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

After payment confirmation, I can go back to payment page and view the details on what user entered. This should not happen

Tried using java script to disable back button but read few recommendations saying its not a good practice to stop user going back. Not sure if there are any decorators like @login_required in django.

How can I force user to see home page even if back button is click on browser after payment confirmation? Does django provide any decorator for the same?

Comment: please make your problem specific, see [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent form fields from repopulating after clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970601/how-to-prevent-form-fields-from-repopulating-after-clicking-the-back-button)